# Altering grids in Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, grids

I am creating grids in Illustrator using this method.

[image]

I want to alter and tweak gutters, margins and columns though. Is there a way to do this or an alternate method? Because right now I have a rectangle shape on a separate layer split into a grid and when I want to update the grid I delete it and just make a new rectangle to redefine the grid.

Comment: Thats a good option. That is what any application eould do too.Illustrator isnt really much a indirect modeller.

Comment: You can't because "Split into grid" actually creates separate physical shapes/objects. It's a destructive operation, so you can't tweak it after you made it, or revert it back to how it was before you did it. It might be nice if there was a non-destructive effect or plugin that could do this, but I'm not aware of any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Split Into Grid` command in Illustrator isn't *really* mean to be a detailed *layout* grid creator. It's meant to merely break apart a rectangle into equal divisions, that's all.

If you want *anything* more custom than standard equal rows and columns you will need to *manually* create/configure your grids.

The good thing is you can create practically anything with paths/shapes and covert those to guides for use as grids via `View > Guide > Make Guides`. So, merely create the grid you want with standard paths, then convert the paths to guides.

The Split into Grid or Rectangular Grid Tool may not always be the best choice if you want uneven sections.